# How to disable user and e-mail input auto-fill?

Tags: forms, 8

I'm trying figure out, how I can disable auto-fill or change markup of 'user' and 'e-mail' input forms, when a user is logged in.

This auto-fill feature is breaking my design, because the 'user' and 'e-mail' markup are just a text inside a div and I can't apply a correct style on it.

[image: Feedback form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in the core stores user login and drupal use this information in every form submit, in other lines, I can't let user change 'user' and 'e-mail' inputs. BUT, I found how to change markup and correct my design. Follow...

In `'mytemplate'\templates\form\form-element.html.twig` I changed:

```
...[omitted]...

78.   {{children}}

...[omitted]...
```

for:

```
{% if logged_in and element['#type'] == 'item' %}
  <input type="text" name="{{name}}" value="{{element['#value']}}" disabled>
{% else %}
  {{ children }}
{% endif %}
```

And my form now looks like this:
[image]